# Node js with mongodb Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: mongodb

One time two request send this error display and my server close

I have use this code:

```
exports.getAllCompany = function (req, res) {         
 Company.find({}, function (err, record) {
    if (err) {
        res.json({
            type: false,
            resultData: "Error occured: " + err
        });
    } else {
        res.json({
            type: true,
            company: record
        });
    }
});}
```

The error message:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)
at ServerResponse.header (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:730:10)
at ServerResponse.send (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
at ServerResponse.json (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:256:15)
at /app/server/mobile_api/AdminController/dashboard.js:279:17
at Query.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3388:16)
at /app/node_modules/kareem/index.js:259:21
at /app/node_modules/kareem/index.js:127:16
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Comment: What method calls getAllCompany? problem should be there... i think you doing res.send there too.

Comment: getAllComapny calls post methods.

Comment: Can you show code ? like app.get(url, function(req,res){calls getAllCompany})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Finally after a long time to solve the issue. follow my answer who have same issue,**

```
 exports.getAllCompany = function (req, res) { 
   res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});        
   Company.find({}, function (err, record) {
     if (err) {
        res.end(JSON.stringify({
         type: false,
         resultData: "Error occured: " + err
        }));
     } else {
        res.end(JSON.stringify({
         type: true,
         company: record
     }));
   }
  });
}
```

Comment: Just add one line **res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"})**
&
change **res.json** to **res.end**

Comment: What I mean is, pasting code on StackOverflow isn't helpful unless you explain _how_ the code answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are calling res.send() more than once

sharing the /app/server/mobile_api/AdminController/dashboard.js file would be helpful

Comment: dashboard.js looks fine.
Could probably be some bad configured hooks within kareem (?)